# How to exclude specific results from grep command inside script

Tags: bash, grep

I have a script that parses DNS info in a certain file. The code looks like this and expects 2 instances of the line from the dump file.

```
nxdom_1st=`grep 'resulted in NXDOMAIN' $path_tmp/named.stats.tmp | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep -m1 ''`
nxdom_2nd=`grep 'resulted in NXDOMAIN' $path_tmp/named.stats.tmp | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort -n | grep -m1 ''`
```

Then, below another command in the script tells it to subtract the results:

```
if [ "$nxdom_1st" == '' ]
then
    nxdomain=0
else
    nxdomain=`expr $nxdom_1st - $nxdom_2nd`
```

Problem is, the dump file eventually contains 4 lines for "resulted in NXDOMAIN", 2 for the actual DNS zone and 2 from localhost, and the script cant handle it so I get no results. For instance, when the dump file contains a pattern like this:

```
             [localhost.localdomain]
             [155.168.192.in-addr.arpa]
             20 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
             20 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
```

In this example the lines with "20" are causing the problem because they are from a local service (I *think*) that is querying itself. Hence the "localhost.localdomain" which always appears before the problem lines. On the server I don't want to disable queries to itself using localhost, so how can I modify the script to discard results if the lines above what its looking for contains [155.168.192.in-addr.arpa] or [localhost.localdomain]?

Below is the file dump that the script parses. Unfortunately, right now there have been no queries to localhost, so you will not see what I posted up above. 
The localhost.localdomain and the [155.168.192.in-addr.arpa] lines are present, just no queries picked up on these 2 stat dumps. Again, this problem only occurs when there are queries listed under these 2 lines, which is why I was wondering if I could modify the grep string in the script to exclude any "resulted in NXDOMIAN" results that may occur directly after. Something like, "if resulted in NXDOMAIN" is seen within 10 lines below "localhost.localdomain", ignore/discard/etc..

```
--- Statistics Dump --- (1443199511)
[id.server (view: _bind)]
[authors.bind (view: _bind)]
[hostname.bind (view: _bind)]
[version.bind (view: _bind)]
[8.B.D.0.1.0.0.2.IP6.ARPA]
[B.E.F.IP6.ARPA]
[A.E.F.IP6.ARPA]
[9.E.F.IP6.ARPA]
[8.E.F.IP6.ARPA]
[D.F.IP6.ARPA]
[0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA]
[255.255.255.255.IN-ADDR.ARPA]
[113.0.203.IN-ADDR.ARPA]
[100.51.198.IN-ADDR.ARPA]
[2.0.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA]
[254.169.IN-ADDR.ARPA]
[127.IN-ADDR.ARPA]
[0.in-addr.arpa]
[1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa]
[1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa]
[localhost]
[localhost.localdomain]
[155.168.192.in-addr.arpa]
[testdns.net]
++ Per Zone Query Statistics ++
              53 UDP/IPv6 send errors
              26 TCP/IPv4 connections accepted
             179 UDP/IPv4 connections established
              53 UDP/IPv6 socket connect failures
              25 TCP/IPv4 sockets closed
              53 UDP/IPv6 sockets closed
             181 UDP/IPv4 sockets closed
               2 TCP/IPv6 sockets opened
               2 TCP/IPv4 sockets opened
              54 UDP/IPv6 sockets opened
             182 UDP/IPv4 sockets opened
++ Socket I/O Statistics ++
[View: _bind (Cache: _bind)]
               4 NXDOMAIN
               1 !DS
               5 DNSKEY
               6 NSEC
              30 RRSIG
               9 DS
              42 AAAA
              20 NS
              75 A
[View: default]
++ Cache DB RRsets ++
[View: _bind]
              20 queries with RTT 100-500ms
             159 queries with RTT 10-100ms
              27 DNSSEC NX validation succeeded
              63 DNSSEC validation succeeded
              90 DNSSEC validation attempted
               2 IPv6 NS address fetch failed
              17 IPv6 NS address fetches
              17 IPv4 NS address fetches
              52 query retries
              18 NXDOMAIN received
             179 IPv4 responses received
              53 IPv6 queries sent
             179 IPv4 queries sent
[View: default]
[Common]
++ Resolver Statistics ++
               2 IPv4 notifies sent
++ Zone Maintenance Statistics ++
              54 queries caused recursion
             625 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
            1270 queries resulted in non authoritative answer
             645 queries resulted in successful answer
            1251 responses with EDNS(0) sent
            1270 responses sent
            1251 requests with EDNS(0) received
            1270 IPv4 requests received
++ Name Server Statistics ++
[View: _bind]
              16 DLV
              22 DNSKEY
              15 DS
              39 AAAA
              12 NS
             128 A
[View: default]
++ Outgoing Queries ++
            1270 A
++ Incoming Queries ++
            1270 QUERY
++ Incoming Requests ++
+++ Statistics Dump +++ (1443199511)
--- Statistics Dump --- (1443199211)
[id.server (view: _bind)]
[authors.bind (view: _bind)]
[hostname.bind (view: _bind)]
[version.bind (view: _bind)]
[8.B.D.0.1.0.0.2.IP6.ARPA]
[B.E.F.IP6.ARPA]
[A.E.F.IP6.ARPA]
[9.E.F.IP6.ARPA]
[8.E.F.IP6.ARPA]
[D.F.IP6.ARPA]
[0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA]
[255.255.255.255.IN-ADDR.ARPA]
[113.0.203.IN-ADDR.ARPA]
[100.51.198.IN-ADDR.ARPA]
[2.0.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA]
[254.169.IN-ADDR.ARPA]
[127.IN-ADDR.ARPA]
[0.in-addr.arpa]
[1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa]
[1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa]
**[localhost]
[localhost.localdomain]
[155.168.192.in-addr.arpa]**
[testdns.net]
++ Per Zone Query Statistics ++
              53 UDP/IPv6 send errors
              25 TCP/IPv4 connections accepted
             172 UDP/IPv4 connections established
              53 UDP/IPv6 socket connect failures
              24 TCP/IPv4 sockets closed
              53 UDP/IPv6 sockets closed
             174 UDP/IPv4 sockets closed
               2 TCP/IPv6 sockets opened
               2 TCP/IPv4 sockets opened
              54 UDP/IPv6 sockets opened
             175 UDP/IPv4 sockets opened
++ Socket I/O Statistics ++
[View: _bind (Cache: _bind)]
               4 NXDOMAIN
               2 !DS
               5 DNSKEY
               6 NSEC
              30 RRSIG
               9 DS
              43 AAAA
              20 NS
              75 A
[View: default]
++ Cache DB RRsets ++
[View: _bind]
              20 queries with RTT 100-500ms
             152 queries with RTT 10-100ms
              24 DNSSEC NX validation succeeded
              60 DNSSEC validation succeeded
              84 DNSSEC validation attempted
               2 IPv6 NS address fetch failed
              17 IPv6 NS address fetches
              17 IPv4 NS address fetches
              52 query retries
              16 NXDOMAIN received
             172 IPv4 responses received
              53 IPv6 queries sent
             172 IPv4 queries sent
[View: default]
[Common]
++ Resolver Statistics ++
               2 IPv4 notifies sent
++ Zone Maintenance Statistics ++
              50 queries caused recursion
             592 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
            1203 queries resulted in non authoritative answer
             611 queries resulted in successful answer
            1185 responses with EDNS(0) sent
            1203 responses sent
            1185 requests with EDNS(0) received
            1203 IPv4 requests received
++ Name Server Statistics ++
[View: _bind]
              16 DLV
              21 DNSKEY
              14 DS
              39 AAAA
              12 NS
             123 A
[View: default]
++ Outgoing Queries ++
            1203 A
++ Incoming Queries ++
            1203 QUERY
++ Incoming Requests ++
+++ Statistics Dump +++ (1443199211)
```

Ok, its happening now, here is a new snippet dump file. Notice the query info under the localhost.localdomain lines: It happens twice in the file.

```
[localhost.localdomain]
[155.168.192.in-addr.arpa]
               1 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
               1 queries resulted in nxrrset
               3 queries resulted in authoritative answer
               1 queries resulted in successful answerenter code here

[localhost]
[localhost.localdomain]
[155.168.192.in-addr.arpa]
               1 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
               1 queries resulted in nxrrset
               3 queries resulted in authoritative answer
               1 queries resulted in successful answer
```

Basically I need the script to ignore these queries and only get the ones for the DNS zone I am using.

Comment: I got a little confused with the question. Could you show us a sample file and the expected result?

Comment: A sample of the script file or a sample of the dump file that it parses?

Comment: The dump file it parses and the expected result. The script seems not necessary as you provided exactly the lines where the parse is.

Comment: Any sample input and output will help

Comment: Sorry guys - my pc that has the dump file locked up. Give me a sec. Thanks..

Comment: Post edited to include dump file.

Answer (score 0):

In case if it results only two lines all the time then you can either `grep` command `sed` command

Using grep:

```
grep -A 2 155.168.192.in-addr.arpa $path_tmp/named.stats.tmp
```

Using sed:

```
sed -n -e '/155.168.192.in-addr.arpa/,+2 p' $path_tmp/named.stats.tmp
```

Comment: 2 lines is what I expect to see. It's when I see 4 lines that causes the problem.